# Ms Access subtracting with a column and average the differences

Tags: ms-access

```
tblStudent
studentid   sex
------------------
1           female
2           male

tblGrade
studentid   subject  Score
--------------------------
1           math     10
2           math     30
1           english  40
2           english  30
1           sci      20
2           sci      50
```

How does an Access query look, that calulates the difference between males and females on their maths and sci score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on `subject` and use the `AVG` aggregate function for the averages.

```
SELECT
    g.subject,
    AVG(IIf(s.sex='male', g.score, null)) AS avg_male,
    AVG(IIf(s.sex='female', g.score, null)) AS avg_female,
    AVG(IIf(s.sex='male', g.score, null)) -
    AVG(IIf(s.sex='female', g.score, null)) AS avg_diff
FROM
    tblStudent s
    INNER JOIN tblGrade g
        ON s.studentid = g.studentid
WHERE g.subject IN ('math', 'sci')
GROUP BY g.subject
```

Note that Access does not include NULL fields in the average calculation. Therefore we can just use NULL when the sex is not the one we need.